# How can I share user space static memory with a PCI device?

Tags: fortran, shared-memory, device-driver, dma, fortran-common-block

**Context**

Hi, I'm porting an ancient 1977 flight simulator program from a SEL computer to a Windows 7 x64 PC system. The program is 500.000 lines written in Fortran, with a large /common/ memory block that is accessed across all modules. This memory is allocated statically.

Additionally, and there my problems begin, there is also a hardware device, that used to access the /common/ block using DMA. We've successfully ported the hardware device to a FPGA PCI device, written a device driver for it and DMA works well.

**The problem:**

I want to share the static memory of the Fortran application with the PCI device.

**Possible solutions**

Things I have considered:

- Allocate memory in the driver and re-map the user space Fortran common block to that area.
- Lock the user space common block in physical memory and tell the PCI device where to read/write.

My preference would be the fist option, because that will avoid lifetime issues. So far I haven't found an acceptable solution. Any tips you could share with me?

Henk.

**Note**: we have full control over hardware and driver, since we built it ourselves, so exotic ideas might help too...

Comment: If you are porting something written in 1977 then presumably it is either Fortran II or Fortran IV.  It will probably all compile in F77.  Does the compiler you are using support Cray pointers?  If it does, then assign the pointer to the shared memory area.

Comment: Yup, gcc has little troubles with the compile. I'll look into Cray pointers.

Comment: With the Fortran ISO_C_Binding you can interface Fortran & C code.  Fortran common variables can be shared with C.  Perhaps that will help?

Comment: You say you are running on W7-64.  Is your code compiled as 32 or 64 bit?  Be aware of integer sizes if you are using Cray pointers in common blocks.  They may have to be declared as integer*8.  Also check the address separation on your PCI device driver: you may have to change them to 8-byte blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wish to know: eventually I found no good solution for this and worked around it with read-copy-modify-write operations. Quite expensive, but since the original program is 45 years old, we had some cpu power to spare :-)